# Querying cases that have some records and not others - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling on how to query a table of patient IDs and diagnoses and return cases which have some diagnoses but not others. I've been playing with self-joins but can't seem to 'get it'. Any help appreciated on this (seemingly!) simple concept... I'm not finding a previous answer to this question on here.

Use case: I need to return a list of patient IDs below who either have 'No Diagnosis' or 'Basal Cell' as a Diagnosis *AND* do not have any other rows for their IDS where Cancer = 'Yes'

Source table

```
[PatientID]     [Diagnosis]       Cancer
1                No Diagnosis     No
1                Basal Cell       No
2                No Diagnosis     No
2                Basal Cell       No            
2                Colon            Yes
3                Breast           Yes
4                Basal Cell       No
5                No Diagnosis     No
```

In the above list, PatientIDs 1, 4 and 5 should be returned because those patients have rows with either 'No Diagnosis' or 'Basal Cell' and no other rows where Cancer = 'Yes'.  PatientID 2 is excluded because they also have a 'Colon' Diagnosis and 3 because they have 'Breast' as a diagnosis.

Hope this makes sense and you're able to help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT [PatientID], [Diagnosis], Cancer
FROM Patients AS p
WHERE [Diagnosis] IN ( 'No Diagnosis', 'Basal Cell') AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Patients  
                  WHERE [PatientID] = p.[PatientID] AND Cancer = 'Yes')
```

The following alternative might seem more verbose but is propably more efficient, since it doesn't make use of a *correlated subquery*, as the above query with `NOT EXISTS` does:

```
SELECT p1.[PatientID], [Diagnosis], Cancer
FROM #Patients AS p1
LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT [PatientID]
   FROM #Patients AS p
   WHERE [Diagnosis] NOT IN ( 'No Diagnosis', 'Basal Cell') AND Cancer = 'Yes'
) AS p2 ON p1.PatientID = p2.PatientID
WHERE [Diagnosis] IN ( 'No Diagnosis', 'Basal Cell') AND p2.PatientID IS NULL
```

Please note that the first predicate of the derived table, i.e. `[Diagnosis] NOT IN ( 'No Diagnosis', 'Basal Cell')`, may not be necessary if both of these diagnosis are never related to cancer.

Comment: @ClintFinch Please note that in my answer I have made the assumption that neither of `'No Diagnosis', 'Basal Cell'` is related to cancer. If this is not the case, then you might have a look at the other answer posted here.

Comment: that was a correct assumption - the 'Cancer' column is an easy way to knock out cancers, while I have more non-cancers than just 'no diagnosis' and basal cell. That works great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.MyTable x
WHERE x.[Diagnosis] IN ('No Diagnosis', 'Basal Cell')
-- AND x.Cancer = 'No' -- I'm not sure from your question if it's needed 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.MyTable y
    WHERE y.PacientID = x.PacientID
    AND x.[Diagnosis] NOT IN ('No Diagnosis', 'Basal Cell') -- I assume that Diagnosis columns is mandatory / NOT NULL
    AND x.Cancer = 'Yes'
)
```

Comment: Note: `[NOT] EXISTS` subqueries should give better performance than `[NOT] IN` / `OUTER JOIN  + IS NULL` alternatives.

Comment: @ClintFinch I am not so sure about that. In this case `NOT EXISTS` utilizes a *correlated subquery*: the subquery will be executed once for every correlated record of the outer query. You may have a look here http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-starters-simple-and-correlated-subqueries

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos : [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join): "NOT EXISTS is typically going to be your best choice. ".

Comment: Anyway, in SQLMag article I don't see any test results.